# ASP.NET equivalent to Classic ASP/CDOSYS method

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, local, cdo.message

I know [How to send e-mail messages by using CDOSYS and the local SMTP directory with Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313773)
Is that method obslete in ASP.NET?
If so, what is the new method?
Please guide me in the right direction.
I am coding in C#.
Regards,
naveenj

Edit: The idea is to send mail using "localhost" as server without authentication

Comment: Both of the answers below are good.  I'd check out all the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SystemNetMail.com](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) should help.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has a wonderful SMTP library to send email

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20211016215613/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080801-1.shtml
http://www.aspheute.com/english/20000918.asp